# Function returning an empty graph

Tags: matlab

This function is supposed to return the answer to a system of linear equations using the gauss seidel method and return a graph of the difference over iterations. So far I've been able to get the function to return the correct answers and the graph is blank. Any tips appreciated.

```
function[x] =  Gauss_Seidel(A,b)
[m, n] = size(A);
[g, v] = size(b);
x= zeros(m, 1);
error = zeros(m, 1);
for iterations = 1:300
    for k = 1:m
        value = 0;
            for j = 1:m
                if j~=k
                    value = value + A(k,j)*x(j);
                end
            end
    x(k) = (b(k)-value)/A(k,k);
    end
end
tdiff = 0;
for j = 1:m
    LHS=0;
    for k=1:m
        LHS=LHS+A(j,k)*x(k);
    end
    difference(j) = abs(b(j)-LHS);
    tdiff = tdiff+difference(j);

end
if tdiff<=error
    iterations
    plot(tdiff,j)
    return
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tdiff and j aren't arrays when you call plot.

Before the loop

```
tdiff = zeros(1,m+1);
steps = zeros(1,m+1); % you need some increment array for your plot
```

In the loop

```
tdiff(j+1) = tdiff(j)+difference(j);
steps(j+1)
```

Just note steps and tdiff start at 0

Comment: Which loop are you referring to? I'm using the fourth loop after `tdiff = 0` for this and now it's telling me that size inputs must be scalar.

Comment: he meant this: `tdiff = zeros(1, m+1); steps = zeros(1, m+1);` (though i'm not sure where `steps` came from -- i think you can remove the `steps`)

Comment: There was a typo, but you're calling plot(tdiff,j) but with your code as written tdiff and j are scalars, so there's nothing to plot. Turning tdiff into a vector that saves each value of tdiff at every iteration, and another vector "steps" to count iterations, will allow you to plot.

Comment: But `steps(j+1)` only logs to console. Did some code get left out when pasting?

Comment: Also can't they just `plot(tdiff)` once `tdiff` is an array? Is `j` or `steps` necessary for `plot`?